# Blender system console character encoding

Tags: interface, command-line

I'm using Blender on Korean Windows 10.
While studying Blender Python I opened the System Console to check for error messages.
By the way, some characters are displayed correctly in English and others are displayed as random characters that have no meaning.
As far as I know, it's probably an encoding issue.
But I don't know how to fix this.
Help...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the Translation option in the Interface tab of the User Preferences causes this problem.
I hope there is no interference between UI Translation and the Systeme Console.